# parsley 2 custom validation not working

Tags: validation, binding, parsley.js

I tried to create a Parsley custom validation but failed. It is never called.

```
$('#test_form').parsley({
validators: {
    customcheck: { 
        fn: function (value, amount) { 
            console.log('?????????????????');
            return 'ok';
        },
        priority: 512
    }
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6fr1ccbf/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems my mistake, this is the official way to do it after loading the JS file of Parsley:

```
window.ParsleyValidator
  .addValidator('multiple', function (value, requirement) {
      console.log('??????????????????');
    return 0 === value % requirement;
  }, 32);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6fr1ccbf/1/